# Disabling a boostrap date picker with add ons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i'm using a bootstrap date picker. I have two date fields to be picked. One is from_date and the other is to_date to provide a range of date. I'm trying enforce the user to select the from_date first for which i want the to_date to be disabled on page load and to be enabled once the from_date is picked. I'm able to disable the text field but the add-on icon that is associated with the date picker is not getting disabled. I'm using jQuery 1.9.1. Can anyone help me out with this.

My JSP looks like this

```
<div id="startTimePicker" class="controls input-append date form_datetime_start" data-link-field="selectedStartTime">
<input size="16" id="startTimePickerText" type="text" value="" readonly>
  <span class="add-on">
   <i class="icon-remove"></i>
  </span>
  <span class="add-on">
   <i class="icon-th"></i>
  </span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="selectedStartTime" value="" />


<div id="endTimePicker" class="controls input-append date form_datetime_end" data-link-field="selectedEndTime">
<input size="16" id="endTimePickerText" type="text" value="" readonly>
 <span class="add-on">
  <i class="icon-remove"></i>
 </span>
 <span class="add-on">
  <i class="icon-th"></i> 
 </span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="selectedEndTime" value="" />
```

Comment: You are using bootstrap 3 ?

Comment: Nope i'm using bootstrap2. Is there a way out in that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the link :- [BOOTSTRAP 2 JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymp5D/422/)

Add the code of to_date here :-

```
 $picker.on('changeDate', function(ev){
     //TO_DATE code
 });
```

Comment: Sadly i'm using a older version of bootstrap :(. Is there any other way out?